# JSON1 support go-sqlite3 using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-sqlite3

In the following example I use `json_extract(...)` using the `go-sqlite3` driver in Golang.

```sh
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    var db *gorm.DB

    type Session struct {
        gorm.Model
        SessionID string `json:"session_id"`
        Options string `json:"options"`
    }

    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "./app.db")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer db.Close() 
    db.AutoMigrate(&Session{})

    var m map[string]int
    m = make(map[string]int)
    m["a"] = 1
    m["b"] = 2
    m["c"] = 3

    js, err := json.Marshal(m)

    sess := Session{
        SessionID: "test",
        Options: string(js),
    }

    db.Create(&sess)
    db.Save(&sess)

    var b = &Session{}

    type Result struct {
        Options string
    }

    // JSON test
    var res Result
    db.Raw("SELECT json_extract(options, '$.a') as Options from sessions").Scan(&res)

    fmt.Println(sess.ID)
    fmt.Println(res)

}
```

The problem is that I cannot get the JSON1 module to be activated when rebuilding the `go-sqlite3` driver. It will error `undefined function: json_extract` on the `db.Raw(...)` line.

In any case, I know that for JSON support, `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` has to be compiled with `-flags "sqlite_json1"`. I've tried several variations:

```sh
go build -a -flags "sqlite_json1"  github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
go install -a -flags "sqlite_json1"  github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
go build -a --flags "sqlite_json1"  github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
go install -a --flags "sqlite_json1"  github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
```

and more variations in `flags`, such as `sqlite_json`, `json`, `json1`, etc. Nothing will get rid of the undefined function error. Any ideas how to properly rebuild `go-sqlite3`?

Obviously I rebuild my own code after that as well.

---

Some info:

go version: `go version go1.13.1 linux/amd64` (platform: Kubuntu 18.04)

go-sqlite3 version: github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 current master

gorm version: github.com/jinzhu/gorm current master

Answer (score 0):

According to `go-sqlite3`'s docs, any of the following flags will work:

- `sqlite_json`
- `sqlite_json1`
- `json1`

Here is the contents of `sqlite3_opt.json1.go` which define the tags that include this file.

```
// Copyright (C) 2014 Yasuhiro Matsumoto <mattn.jp@gmail.com>.
//
// Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

// +build sqlite_json sqlite_json1 json1

package sqlite3

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1
*/
import "C"
```

Reference: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/sqlite3_opt_json1.go

Also to point out, you're using `--flags` in your `go build` command, but give `--tags` a try instead.

Comment: Both `--tags` and `--flags` with any of the values `sqlite_json`, `sqlite_json1` and `json1` still produce a build with the same errors.

Strangely enough, doing it directly in the C amalgamation does work, ie:
`#define SQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 1` in `sqlite3-binding.c` and running `go build -a` in the `src` directory.